# Refer to table body in new environment

Tags: tabularx, booktabs

I'm trying to create a new environment based on `tabularx`. I'd like it to have a `\bottomrule` at the end. How do I refer to the table rows on the new environment definition? Right now the bottom line is appearing above the rows instead of below them.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, tabularx}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\hsize=#1\hsize\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\newenvironment{funtab}[1]{%
  \tabularx{\textwidth}{@{} L{0.4} L{0.6} L{2.0} @{}}
    \toprule
    Operation&\multicolumn{2}{l}{#1}\\
    \midrule
    %Table body location <------------------------
    \bottomrule
}{%
  \endtabularx
}

\begin{document}

\begin{funtab}{My function name goes here}
  item1 & item2 & item 3 \\
  item1 & item2 & item 3 which is long and should wrap around around around around \\
\end{funtab}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently using `\tabularx....\endtabularx` 'annoys' `\bottomrule`, leaving no real `tabular` environment group, so group the `\tabularx...` content.

In any case the `\bottomrule` must be shifted to the `\end...` part of the tabular environment if it should appear there.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, tabularx}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\hsize=#1\hsize\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\newenvironment{funtab}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \tabularx{\textwidth}{@{} L{0.4} L{0.6} L{2.0} @{}}
    \toprule
    Operation&\multicolumn{2}{l}{#1}\\
    \midrule
    % Table body location <------------------------
}{%
  \bottomrule
  \endtabularx
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\begin{funtab}{My function name goes here}
  item1 & item2 & item 3 \\
  item1 & item2 & item 3 which is long and should wrap around around around around \\
\end{funtab}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What are `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` for?

Comment: @egreg: Good question: It just does not work without the outer group

Comment: Really? I just get an overfull because of the indentation box and another because “Operation” doesn't fit, but no other problems, when I remove `\begingroup` and `\endgroup`.

Comment: @egreg: I get no bottom rule -- the table is there of course

Comment: @egreg: Yes -- either I misunderstood the question or the question is misleading with `refer to body` etc. (I get the overfull box warnings too, of course)

Comment: Oh! You refer to *that*? ;-) Blame the package author!

Comment: It does work without the group when a `\par` is added at the end. (This is a strange behaviour of `\bottomrule` IMHO)

Comment: @clemens: Thanks, but what does the group do then? It does not add a `\par` implicitly?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I have no idea what's happening